# Proof that finite group contains an element of prime order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I tried to prove the following claim but it seemed a bit too easy:

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Then $G$ contains an element of prime order.

Please could someone tell me if my proof is correct or if I'm missing something?

Let $g$ be any non-identity element of $G$. Let $p$ be any prime factor of $|g|$. Then $g^{|g|\over p}$ has prime order $p$. $\Box$

Comment: A group of order $1$ contains no element of prime order.

Comment: Its OK. but his proof shows he want to consider $G\neq 1$.

Comment: Consider $G=\mathbb{Z}_6$, the additive cyclic group. Choose $p=3$, $g=3$, the $g^{(6/3)}=3+3=0$, with order 1! I believe this is a counter example to the proof. The theorem you are trying to proof is correct, but the proof is not..

Comment: @MorganRodgers oh... Yes, you are right! Serious misunderstanding on my part..

Answer (score 5):

Yes. This is right. To ensure it:

If $|g|$ is a prime, then we are done. Let $p$ be a prime factor of $|g|$, so that $|g|>p$.

Let $h=g^{\frac{|g|}{p}}$. Then $h^p=g^{|g|}=1$, which implies that order of $h$ divides $p$, so it is $1$ or $p$.

If order of $h$ is $1$ then this means, $h=1$ i.e. $g^{|g|/p}=1$, i.e. $|g|\leq |g|/p$, this is contradiction.

Comment: But you can't let $g^{|g|\over p}$ equal $1$. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No on your second line. It starts with "Let ..."

Comment: Now corrected with details. Thanks for noticing errors.

Answer (score -4):

No the proof is not correct. It is possible that $g^{\frac{|g|}{p}}=e$. The theorem you are stating is commonly called Cauchy's theorem.  There is an elementary proof [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/cauchypf.pdf) using the class equation.

Comment: See whether he wants to prove Cauchy's theorem or something weaker.

Comment: @Groups Your answer above is flawed. $h^p=1$ does not mean that the prder of $h$ is $p$ or $1$ it can be any divisor of $\frac{|g|}{p}$.

Comment: Actually there is no need to evoke Cauchy's Theorem to prove this exercise.

Comment: No, it is correct.

Comment: I think that Aloysius' answer is correct, surprised at all the downvotes

Comment: @MorganRodgers in the proof it seems to work for any $p$, which is cauchy's theorem?

Comment: @MorganRodgers In any case the proof you have detailed is not correct!

Comment: The proof in the question is correct (well, with a small adjustment in case $g$ has prime order itself), and the exercise is a way weaker statement than Cauchy's theorem.